# Usage of "they/them" with objects

Tags: plural-forms

Is it correct to use "they/them" when it's not about people? For example:

> I dropped all the books; they lay on the floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct since in your sentence *they* means the subject of the first sentence- books. And there's nothing wrong in using they/them for referring to non-human objects like books.

But I must say, the sentence seems a bit off. You can alternatively say it as:

> I dropped all the books on the floor.

Answer (score 0):

While it is common for people to use they and them and their when referring to objects it not really proper. The one answer is incorrect about the subject of the sentence being books. I is the subject and books is the object. I dropped al of the books. Those lay on the floor. Use of a semi colon is not right. Two separate sentences should be used. Or one sentence stating I dropped all the books to the floor. In modern times it seems that they, them, and theirs are commonly used even if what is being discussed are neuter. These, those, and its should be used.

Comment: This is just wrong. It is completely fine to use *they/them* with objects. Who told you otherwise?